# Как вывести значение input без кнопок!

Tags: php, html, input

Как вывести значение input на другую страницу или в какой-то массив php или подобное, без кнопок,сделать автоматическим, возможно ли это?

Comment: через get параметры. в адресе другой странице добавьте ?a=значение_input и выведите там, где нужно

Comment: а как именно это можно реализовать, я понял что <a href="http://localhost/?<?php var_dump($_GET)?> (что именно тут написать)> button </a>, можете показать пример

Answer (score 0):

Пока не могу писать комментарии поэтому отвечу.
Чтобы передать $_GET через ссылку можно вот так:

```
<a href="localhost/?id=<?=$_GET['id']?>">ID: <?=$_GET['id']?></a>
```

Допустим у вас в адресной строке http://localhost/?id=5

Ссылка будет такая:

```
<a href="localhost/?id=5">ID: 5</a>
```